# Frame Replacement?

Tags: html, html-frames

I'm currently redesigning an old web application that relies heavily on frames.  I'd like to get rid of the frames because the painful javascript gyrations they require, but would still like the user to have a movable border between two parts of the screen (view and attributes).

What html element, or html element + javascript, can I use to replace frames?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6173699/309483

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any solutions that won't involve JavaScript. If you're OK with that, you could replace them with `<div>` elements and use JavaScript to make them resizeable.

Comment: JavaScript is completely acceptable, as long as the whole thing is logically in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I see no other solution than a `div`. But you would have to use JS again to allow the dragging of the border. Use of JQuery would be fine here as there is maybe a plugin for that, check the database.