# Can HTML5 have resizable frames?

Tags: html, iframe, frameset

Here is a working example of frames in HTML5:

```
<html>
<head><title>NP Framer v1.0</title></head>
<noframes>
<body>
Your browser doesn't support frames.  Please click <a href="http://www.duckduckgo.com">here</a> to be redirected to the new page.
</body>
</noframes>
<frameset framespacing="0" rows="150,*" frameborder="0" resize>
<frame name="top" src="http://www.npscripts.com/framer/demo-top.html" target="top">
<frame name="main" src="http://www.duckduckgo.com" target="main">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Here is a working example of resizable DIV content (not frames) [Resizable frame emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173699/resizable-frame-emulation)

It is possible to have resizable frames in HTML5? (Where you can drag the divider between the two frames.)

My use case is Chrome casting my browser tab to the office TV. Usually I just want to see the dashboard. But I'd also like music on there. So sometimes I want to make the music tab bigger so I can adjust it.

Comment: What's you question?

Comment: Thank you, I have reworded it to be more clear.

Comment: Framesets shouldn't be used, are deprecated, and will be removed in the future. So I'd recommend against using them

Answer (score 0):

Solution. Yes you can use resizable frames in HTML5. It will probably break in the future but it works today in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<frameset cols="*,*">
  <frame src="tv">
  <frame id="music">
</frameset>
</html>
```